# How to compose functions with two argumens?

Tags: purescript

I know I can do:

```hs
fn1 :: B -> C

fn2 :: (A -> B) -> (A -> C)
fn2 callback = callback >>> fn2
```

But how do I compose (`>>>`) a function with two arguments?:

```hs
fn3 :: (Z -> A -> B) -> (Z -> A -> C)
fn3 callback = callback (\z a -> fn1 z a # fn2) ✅

fn3' :: (Z -> A -> B) -> (Z -> A -> C)
fn3' callback = callback (???) fn2 -- >>> won't work
```

What should `???` operator be to return be exactly like `>>>` but taking the additional parameter needed for `fn1` before running `fn2` as `>>>` won't work?

#### more concretely

I'm trying to FFI this function more elegantly

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.onRequestImp = function (handler) {
  return functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    handler(request)(response)();
  });
}
```

```hs
module Firebase.Functions.HTTP (onRequest) where

import Prelude

import Control.Promise (Promise, fromAff)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Aff (Aff)
import Node.Express.Types (Request, Response)

foreign import onRequestImp :: (Request -> Response -> Effect (Promise (Unit))) -> Effect Unit

onRequest :: (Request -> Response -> Aff (Unit)) -> Effect Unit
onRequest handler = do
  onRequestImp
    ( \req res -> do
        handler req res # fromAff
    )
```

Comment: Your type annotation for `fn3` in the first code block is incorrect.

Comment: And in the second code block, the body of `fn3` is calling `fn1` and passing it a function as an argument, but `fn1` cannot accept a function, because its first parameter is of type `A`, which is not a function. Unless `A` is defined as a type synonym for a function type, in which case could you paste its definition as well?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @FyodorSoikin, yep `fn3` is how I'm doing it, I'm wondering if there's something to "lift" `>>>` to work on fn with two parameters, so it returns a fn with takes an additional param before calling the right side `fn2`, what would (???) expression/operator be?

Comment: What do you mean by "fn3 is how I'm doing it"? The code as you posted it does not compile!

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, my example was a miswritten oversimplification of how to change the final return type of a callback with 2 args if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your type signatures seem way off. In your first code block, with the definition of `fn3` that you provide, it should look like this:

```
fn3 :: A -> C
fn3 = fn1 >>> fn2
```

Similarly, if I understood the spirit of the question right, in the second code block, the composed type should be:

```
fn3 :: A -> B -> D
```

That is, you take the output of `fn1` and give it as input to `fn2`.

---

With that out of the way, let's talk about composition. The answer is: yes and no.

No, there is no such composition operator/function in the standard library, because it's usually not useful. Composing functions like this heavily obscures what's going on and makes your program that much harder to maintain.

But also, yes, there is such composition operator/function defined in a library that is specifically aimed at writing point-free programs - [`compose2` and its friend `compose2Flipped`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-point-free/1.0.0/docs/PointFree#v:compose2), aliased in operator form as `<..` and `..>` respectively:

```
import PointFree ((..>))

fn1 :: A -> B -> C
fn2 :: C -> D

fn4 :: A -> B -> D
fn4 = fn1 ..> fn2
```

---

Having said that, I strongly advise against using such composition. Point-free notation is neat and cool, but in practice it just makes your program incomprehensible. Much better just to write exactly what you mean:

```
fn4 :: A -> B -> D
fn4 a b = fn2 (fn1 a b)
```

---

P.S. Here's a neat trick: how do you think I found that library? It's not like I have all the libraries and all their types and functions memorized, right?

I used the Pursuit search. I knew the type signature of the function you seek would be `(a -> b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> d)` and I just plugged that into search, and voila!

Here, try it yourself: https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=(a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c)+-%3E+(c+-%3E+d)+-%3E+(a+-%3E+b+-%3E+d)

Comment: Thanks for a more readable re-write! I did try to use Pursuit but searched for a less accurate signature 